# Posting multiple content types to web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, content-type

I have a web api and I would like to post an image file + some data in order to process it correctly when it is received at the server.

The calling code looks something like this:

```
using(var client = new HttpClient())
using(var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
{
  client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/");
  var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(File.ReadAllBytes(fileName));
  fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
   {
     FileName = "foo.jpg"
   };

   content.Add(fileContent);
   FeedItemParams parameters = new FeedItemParams()
   {
     Id = "1234",
     comment = "Some comment about this or that."
   };
   content.Add(new ObjectContent<FeedItemParams>(parameters, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()), "parameters");
   content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("multipart/form-data");

   var result = client.PostAsync("/api/ImageServices", content).Result;
```

And the web api method signature looks like this:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]FeedItemParams parameters)
```

When I run this I get an `UnsupportedMediaType` exception. I know this has something to do with the `ObjectContent`, since this method worked when I was passing just an `ID` in the query string instead of the object in the body.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

WebAPI built-in formatters only support the following media types: `application/json`, `text/json`, `application/xml`, `text/xml` and `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

For `multipart/form-data`, which is what you are sending, take a look at [Sending HTML Form Data](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/sending-html-form-data,-part-2) and [ASP.NET WebApi: MultipartDataMediaFormatter](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/652633/ASP-NET-WebApi-MultipartDataMediaFormatter)

Sample client

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:54711/");

        content.Add(new StreamContent(File.OpenRead(@"d:\foo.jpg")), "foo", "foo.jpg");

        var parameters = new FeedItemParams()
        {
            Id = "1234",
            Comment = "Some comment about this or that."
        };
        content.Add(new ObjectContent<FeedItemParams>(parameters, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()), "parameters");

        var result = client.PostAsync("/api/Values", content).Result;
    }
}
```

Sample controller if you follow the first article

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostFormData()
{
    // Check if the request contains multipart/form-data.
    if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
    }

    string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
    var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);

    // Read the form data.
    await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

    //use provider.FileData to get the file
    //use provider.FormData to get FeedItemParams. you have to deserialize the JSON yourself

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Turns out that if you want to use `multipart/form-data`, you need to yank the content out of the request, since as you said, web api will not do it for you. Still, an easy enough solution.